# Override sass variable from different project

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I have multiple projects where I want to override scss color variable from two different projects.

for example, 
if I'm running project A I want $primaryColor to be red
and if I'm running project B I want the $primaryColor to be green

My Project Tree
- Project_A
- Project_B
- Shared_Component_Library
- Style_Library
    - color_palette.scss

both Project_A and Project_B are using the Shared_Component_Library
and the Shared_Component_Library get its style from Style_Library.

how can I override the scss color variable with different value when I run my different project?

if it helps I'm using angular-cli in order to build this multiple projects

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways ....

**First** :

You've got to put in each project a small scss file with the variable overrided... Those files should include your shared scss file... But it will create 2 files....

**First and Half** :

If you dont' want to duplicate your whole css file, you can just extract the scss component you need to override in antoher file, which will be duplicated...

**Second** :

If you are not limited and can make the exception of IE11 (look at here https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), instead af using scss variables, you can just use a css variable...

**PS**:

I don't give you some code, maybe do you need to see how you can include and overide ?

You could take a look at how is bootstrap 4 done with scss, you'll see how the variables are done...